# Name for formula of $p(x + 1) - p(x)$ where $p$ is a polynomial

Tags: polynomials, reference-request, terminology

Let $p(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + \cdots + a_N x^N$ be a polynomial of degree $N$ ($a_0 = 0$ wlog), and let $q(x) = p(x+1)-p(x)$.

Then, it is easy to verify that $q(x) = b_0 + b_1x+ \cdots + b_{N-1}x^{N-1}$ where
\begin{align}
b_0 &=\sum_{n=1}^N a_n, \\
b_1 &= \sum_{n=2}^N n a_n, \\
b_2 &= \sum_{n=3}^N \frac{n(n-1)}{2} a_n, \\
&\vdots \\
b_k &= \sum_{n=k+1}^N \binom{n}{k} a_n.
\end{align}

**My question**: Do these formulas above have a name? Is it just Newton's binomial? If I had to use these formulas in a wider scope and use the correct naming for them, what should I say?

Comment: They look very close to binomial coefficients

Comment: This is the method of differences. I'm unaware of a special name for the coefficients $b_i$. We call $q(x)$ the first difference.